# Generating truncated piecewise constant exponential random variables

Tags: r, dplyr, simulation, plyr, exponential

I am trying to generate piecewise constant exponential random variables which are truncated on both sides. But in my case each time the left truncation point will change and as well as the rates of the each time point. That is each number has to be larger than the entry age and less than or equal to 89. I have to generate 50,000 numbers.

I have tried the following code, which is okay while generating 1000-2000 random numbers, but taking forever when I want to generate 50,000. Is there any way I can do it faster?

```
library(PWEALL)
time_breaks = c(0,18,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85)
cbc.hazard.sim=
c(0.000000000,0.001232438,0.001857680,0.002381863,0.002678475, 
0.003070916,0.003068740,0.003400704, 0.003407023,
0.004028654, 0.003825065, 0.004224777, 0.003891890, 0.003590939)

cbc.time=function(x,y,cbc_hazard,time_interval){
repeat {
  cbc_time=rpwe(1, rate=cbc_hazard*x, tchange=time_interval)

  if(cbc_time>y & cbc_time<=89) {
    return(cbc_time)
    break
  }
 }

  }

 rr.test=c(rep(1.5,15000), rep(2,15000), rep(2.25,10000), rep(2.5,10000))
 age_entry=c(rep(35,10000), rep(45,30000), rep(65,10000))

cbc.age=unlist(mapply(cbc.time, rr.test,age_entry,MoreArgs = 
list(cbc_hazard=cbc.hazard.sim,time_interval=time_breaks)))
```

I have also tried the 'rpexp' function from the 'msm' package, but no luck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the phrase " piecewise constant exponential random variables". How can something be "piecewise constant" and also "exponential" and what would it mean for a random variable to be both of htose things????

Comment: That is exponential distribution with piecewise-constant rate. This is very common in survival analysis, where hazard rate is assumed constant in intervals. This link might be helpful:http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s4.html

Comment: Wouldn't you be calling  function `pwe`? If not then we need to comments to understand what ypu are actually attempting. And as far as R coding is concerned you should first be looking at the code that creates `cbc.hazard.sim`. It's a mess. Before posting a question its a good idea to start a new sessipn and see whether you code runs without error.

Comment: My apologies, I think I missed c in creating the cbc.hazard.sim. I have corrected it. Thank you.